# Can a basis of $\mathbb R^n$ contain complex vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I think that this should be false. But on the other hand I am thinking that if we multiply a complex vector with a complex number be can get a real vector. So just wanted to make sure. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The basis elements have to elements fo the space, so it is indeed not possible.

Comment: Well, if $n$ is even and without more context ...

Answer (score 2):

A complex vector $v$ is not a member of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and therefore, cannot be in a basis of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.